# Tradingview: exit with a Trailing SL on historical bars behaves strangely

Tags: pine-script

Here is a very simple strategy that enters a long position on even index bars. And that exits at the same time with a trailing stop loss.

```
//@version=5
strategy("TEST STRATEGY 2", overlay=true)

backtestStartDate = input.time(timestamp("01 Apr 2023 12:05:00 GMT+02:00"), title="Start Date", group="Backtest Time Period")
backtestEndDate = input.time(timestamp("01 Apr 2023 16:15:00 GMT+02:00"), title="End Date", group="Backtest Time Period")
inTradeWindow = time > backtestStartDate and time <= backtestEndDate

longCondition = bar_index % 2 == 0

if inTradeWindow

    if longCondition
        strategy.entry("My Long Entry "+str.tostring(bar_index), strategy.long)
        strategy.exit("My Short Entry "+str.tostring(bar_index), from_entry = "My Long Entry "+str.tostring(bar_index), trail_offset=50, trail_points=50)
```

[image]

As you can see, on the candle of 12:58 (pointed with the big red arrow), the trade closed just below the high of the candle (and **the difference between the high and this point is very small: -1.05 pip!**).

Yet, **the *trail_offset* was set to 50 pips**, so, it should have close way below, isn't it ?

Thanks

**[EDIT]**

with `trail_offset=50*syminfo.mintick , trail_points=50*syminfo.mintick`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With trail_offset=50 you didn't set the trail_offset to 50 pips but to 50 ticks.
To look at the value of 50 ticks, you can execute :

```
MyValue = 50 * syminfo.mintick
```

the result depends on the pair you use for your chart.

From the manual :

> **trail_points** (series int/float) An optional parameter. Trailing stop activation level (profit specified in ticks). If it is specified, a trailing stop order will be placed when the calculated price level(specified amount of profit) is reached. The offset (in ticks) to determine initial price of the trailing stop order is specified in the'trail_offset' parameter: X ticks lower than activation level to exit long position; X ticks higher than activation level to exit short position. The default value is 'NaN'.

> **trail_offset** (series int/float) An optional parameter. Trailing stop price (specified in ticks). The
> offset in ticks to determine initial price of the trailing stop order:
> X ticks lower than 'trail_price' or 'trail_points' to exit long
> position; X ticks higher than 'trail_price' or 'trail_points' to exit
> short position. The default value is 'NaN'.

I think you should only use trail_offset in your case.

Comment: I just tried your solution but as you can see on the edit, the problem now is on the candle of 13h03

Comment: actually, simply setting the appropriate number of ticks was good enought, you can see this number of ticks with the measure tool (number at the top right). In my case I have set up 500.